# How do I make an image only overflow (hidden) on the bottom if it exceeds it's container div?

Tags: html, css

Here is a fiddle detailing my code: http://jsfiddle.net/naj202uj/

HTML

```
<!-- Landscape image -->
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://thomaslawnscapes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrisweb1.jpg"/>
</div>

<!-- Square image -->
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg"/>
</div>

<!-- Portrait image -->
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://images.sussexpublishers.netdna-cdn.com/article-inline-half/blogs/38/2009/01/3116-76084.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: black solid 1px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100px;
}
```

As you can see the images in the divs (divs always a fixed landscape size) don't get stretched, but the overflow is hidden. As you can see with the portrait image, it overflows on the top and the bottom. How do I only cut off the image at the bottom and align the top of the image to the top of the container div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add object-position: top center; to the container img
 and it will align the image to the top of the container :)